# Python -- validate tuples in a list have the same length

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
x = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]

for tup in x:
     if len(tup) == 3:
        print(True) 
     else:
        print(False)
```

I want to validate tuples in a list have the same length of 3. If any of the tuples in the list has more or less than 3 values, I want to print single output `False`. If all the tuples have 3 values then it should print single output `True`.

Currently, the for loop produces more than 1 output. How do I tweak the for loop?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `all()`:

```
if all(len(tup) == 3 for tup in x):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: You get a warning from the Department of Redundancy Department! Never use `if/else` to just print out True or False. Use the boolean directly from `all` ;)

Comment: I agree, but I'm perhaps incorrectly assuming the OP has 2 branches of logic and is just printing for MCVE - but he does explicitly ask to print. I would update but @DanilSperansky has the one-liner covered.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner:

```
print(all(len(t) == 3 for t in x))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I'd _never_ use the `set` version if I had the `all` version available to me.  Specifically, `all` is more clear and it has the ability to short-circuit as soon as it finds a tuple of the wrong length.  The `set` version` will always look at _every_ tuple before coming to a decision.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient solution for this problem is to use the `break` keyword and loop manipulation like so:

```
x = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
tupleCheck = True
for tup in x:
    if len(tup) != 3:
       tupleCheck = False # Here, the program realizes that a tuple does not have a length of 3...
       break # and aborts.
print(tupleCheck)
```

Although somewhat redundant, this solution is quite readable.

Comment: So much code and slower compare to the use of a list comprehension and all()

Comment: @Y0da I'm trying to go with OP's idea of "tweaking the for loop" instead of completely demolishing everything and making a one-liner. But still, using list comp + all() is the better solution if the aforementioned "tweak" was not mentioned.

Comment: I get the motivation but in my opinion this is not readable compare to the list comp + all() which is way more pythonic. This kind of answer (@danil-speransky) help everyone to be more pythonic and write better code =)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `namedTuple`. Instead of checking the list of point you could create your list of point using this. [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(11, y=22)     # instantiate with positional or keyword arguments
```

Comment: I actually really like this approach.  It's better to force the formatting of the data-structure when you create it rather than needing to check it at every point where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

This gives a list corresponding to each tuple:

```
x=[(1,2,3),(1,2,2)]
d=[len(a)==3 for a in x]
p=True
for i in d:
    p= i and p
print p
```